# What's the Purpose of defer in a Tcp connection listerner

Tags: go

I recently started learning TCP, I understand how defer works in terms of files creation and some other things but what I don't understand about the use of defer in TCP is that when a server is listening for an incoming request, it's like an infinity loop such that the TCP never stops listening to request except it is interrupted by the command line.

Take for instance the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func listenConnection(conn net.Conn) {
    for {
        buffer := make([]byte, 1400)
        size, err := conn.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Connection closed")
            return
        }

        data := buffer[:size]
        fmt.Printf("recieved message %s", data)

        _, err = conn.Write(data)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
    }
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Listening to localhost:5000")
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:5000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    defer listener.Close()

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("New connection")
        go listenConnection(conn )
    }
}
```

How does the defer statement work in this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1):

It works the same in any context: It executes upon completion of the containing function. In this case, when `main()` terminates, the deferred function will run.

Your confusion seems to be around the idea that there's an infinite loop in `main()`. There actually isn't one:  The loop will terminate when `listener.Accept()` returns an error, because then `log.Fatal` is called, which terminates the entire program.

Comment: Wow. Thanks @flimzy

Comment: Quick Question: what can trigger an error in listener.Accept() excluding command line interruption @Flimzy

Comment: The best way to answer that is to read the source code: https://golang.org/src/net/tcpsock.go?s=7294:7338#L247